# How to add a randomColumn to a Feature Collection while maintaining strata in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest, stratified-sampling

I am creating training and test data for a Random Forest model using Google Earth Engine (Python API).

I have used [stratifiedSample()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-stratifiedsample) to create a Feature Collection of sample points within my training polygons. I would like to use [randomColumn()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-randomcolumn) to assign a pseudo-random float to each feature so I can then split them into training and test sets using a threshold.

**How do I ensure the random numbers are assigned per strata**, in this case per the column `class`?

I see that [ee.Reducer has a group method](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-group) but this is not applicable for Feature Collections.

My current code, in which I am unsure if the strata were respected when adding the `randomColumn`:

```py
## make a feature collection of training polygons
fc = ee.FeatureCollection(polygons)

## create an empty object to hold stratified points
classes = ee.Image().byte().paint(polygons, "class").rename("class")

## stratify sample points per feature
stratified = classes.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat()).stratifiedSample(
      numPoints = 1000,
      classBand = 'class',
      projection = 'EPSG:4326',
      scale = 10,
      region = fc,
      geometries = True
    )

## add a random number to each feature   
stratified = stratified.randomColumn()

## sample image using stratified points ('random' is the default column name given by randomColumn)
sample = img.select(train_bands).sampleRegions(collection=stratified, properties=['class', 'random'], scale=10)

## define fraction for training (remainder is for testing)
split = 0.7

## divide into training and testing sets based on the split
training = sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split))
validation = sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random numbers from randomColumn are uniformly distributed.  That means just taking 30% of the whole collection will take 30% of each strata, to within a small statistical margin.  You can tell how many in each with a reduceColumns and a frequencyHistogram on the class property, after the filter.

If you *really* think you need an exact amount of each class (seems unlikely) then you should run stratified sample twice, once for training (numPoints: 700) and once for validation (numPoints: 300).

To guarantee that there are no validation points within a certain distance of the training points (or on top of them), you can mask the inputs with a (potentially buffered) version of the training points before taking the validation sample.

Also:

1. you don't really need to add a pixelLonLat band AND run it with {geometries: true}.  The geometries already have the lon/lat in them.
2. You shouldn't run stratifiedSample and then sampleRegions on the outputs; just add the training bands to the classes and run stratifiedSample on that whole thing.

Comment: Thank you, Noel. After a rethink, I realised that indeed the strata will be sampled uniformly and I was actually about to take my question down until I saw your answer. Thank you for the extra tips, which I have now implemented.